# Alternate DNS server in Internet wi-fi connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, dns, android

I'm using Android GSM mobile phone hotspot in order to get Internet in my laptop. Hotspot provides me IP and DNS server address. But I would like to use DNS server from Google I usually use 8.8.8.8. How to change DNS server address in my wi-fi connection?

Comment: Look up the documentation for your hotspot and see if you can do that.

Comment: this question has been asked multiple times on https://android.stackexchange.com